# Failed building wheel for twisted

Tags: software-installation, python, django

I made a virtualenv, and a new blank django project. I want to install Channels. I'm using Python 3.6.3. I typed `pip install -U channels` and this is output:

```
...
Failed building wheel for twisted
...
Command "/home/marcin/Documents/django_projects/channels/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ic8ux9ei/twisted/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ox6bclm5-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/marcin/Documents/django_projects/channels/include/site/python3.6/twisted" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ic8ux9ei/twisted/
```

`pip list` **OUTPUT**:

```
...
Django (1.11.6)
...
pip (9.0.1)
...
setuptools (36.6.0)
...
wheel (0.29.0)
...
```

I see that I don't have Twisted, so I typed: `pip install twisted`. This is the output:

```
...
 Failed building wheel for twisted
...
Command "/home/marcin/Documents/django_projects/channels/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-a54n37_z/twisted/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-9p23ehnv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/marcin/Documents/django_projects/channels/include/site/python3.6/twisted" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-a54n37_z/twisted/
```

As you can see, the outputs are almost the same. How can I install Channels?

Comment: You might be missing a few packages that are installed using apt. Try `sudo apt install python3.6-dev` and then repeat the installation process for pip.

Comment: Sounds good; I will write an answer in case there are other people who face the same problem :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error message is not particularly helpful but it seems you are missing the `python3.6-dev` package, which is installed using `apt`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.6-dev
```

After this, repeat your installation using pip as before.

Answer (score 6):

You also need to the `build-essential` package if it hasn't been installed already.  The complete install command is:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python3.6-dev
```

Comment: that was indeed my problem, according to my python version, 3.5

Comment: I had installation problems related to rasa core on my Ubuntu machine. This fixed it. Thanks Steve.

Comment: sure, this works for me

Comment: This helped me on 20.04 using python 3.8

Answer (score -1):

Faced a similar issue while installing rasa_core.

Resolved an issue in a couple of steps:

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-esssential python3.6-dev
```

Finally able to install rasa_core successfully.

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU.  Please refrain from posting answers similar or equal to existing ones.  Instead, upvote the one(s) that you solved the problem.  This ensures future readers to easily get to the most satisfying answer instead of reading mutiple time the same story.